# Interval of 30 days in MYSQL Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Are these both query same :

```
SELECT count(site_key) as count_lic FROM (`activation`) 
  WHERE    `site_key` = '36LYRAHK0100000000B6101442Cs' AND `user_id` = '' AND `request_time` = 'BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()




SELECT count(site_key) as count_lic FROM (`activation`) WHERE `site_key` = '36LYRAHK0100000000B6101442Cs' AND `user_id` = '' AND `request_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Can we use **'request_time' = 'BETWEEN.......'** ?

I am using PHP Codeigniter and I have done :

```
function fGetUsedLicenses($site_id) {

    //count number of activations without user_id
    $this->db->select('count(site_key) as count_lic');
    $this->db->where('site_key', $site_id);
    $this->db->where('user_id','');
    $this->db->where('request_time', 'BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()');
    $this->db->from('activation');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();
    $count = $result->count_lic;

    echo $this->db->last_query();
    //count number of activations with unique user_id
    $this->db->select('count(DISTINCT user_id) as count_lic');
    $this->db->where('site_key', $site_id);
    $this->db->where('user_id !=','');
    $this->db->where('request_time', 'BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()');
    $this->db->from('activation');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();
    $count += $result->count_lic;

    var_dump($count);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    exit(0);
    return $count;
}
```

Now If I use this way the query generated is 'request_time' 'BETWEEN.....'

Comment: should be like `..request_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() ...`. `BETWEEN` doesn't take an equal operator before it.

Comment: @1000111 i also thought so but how do i do this in Codeigniter

Comment: request_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)...

Comment: @splash58 showed me mysql error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 5

SELECT count(site_key) as count_lic FROM (`activation`) WHERE `site_key` = '36LYRAHK0100000000B6101442Cs' AND `user_id` = '' AND `request_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 0`

Comment: @Rajan is it about my comment or answer?

Comment: it was about your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it like

```
->where('request_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()', "", false);
```